# how to load image of a movie from tmdb json feed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, themoviedb-api

**Fragment code**

//get the posters of movies

```
                String urlPOster = null;

                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_POSTER)) {

                    urlPOster = currentMovies.getString(URL_POSTER +KEY_POSTER);
                }
```

**URL_POSTER and KEY_POSTER**

public static final String KEY_POSTER="poster_path";

public static final String URL_POSTER="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";

**json feed of tmdb**

```
results": [{
"adult": false,
"backdrop_path": "/o4I5sHdjzs29hBWzHtS2MKD3JsM.jpg",
"genre_ids": 
[878,
28,
53,
12],
"id": 87101,
"original_language": "en",
"original_title": "Terminator Genisys",
"overview": "The year is 2029. John Connor, leader of the resistance continues the war against the machines. At the Los Angeles offensive, John's fears of the unknown future begin to emerge when TECOM spies reveal a new plot by SkyNet that will attack him from both fronts; past and future, and will ultimately change warfare forever.",
"release_date": "2015-07-01",
"poster_path": "/5JU9ytZJyR3zmClGmVm9q4Geqbd.jpg",
"popularity": 55.202911,
"title": "Terminator Genisys",
"video": false,
"vote_average": 6.4,
"vote_count": 183},
```

**here is my adapter class**

```
    final String urlPoster=currentMovies.getUrlPOster();
    if (urlPoster!=null){

        imageLoader.get(urlPoster, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                holder.movieThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Use Picasso an android image loading library. Just search on google. And check this one too https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dimiourgos.knowmyshow

Answer (score 1):

**Suggest** [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)  , You can load your URL.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.you_image_view);
Glide.with(this)
  .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/o4I5sHdjzs29hBWzHtS2MKD3JsM.jpg")
  .into(imageView);
```

Comment: can you suggest me where to add this Glide in my code?

Comment: Would you like to download image into your storage or just show within image view or you want to phase json to object.

Comment: just to show within the image view anyways i solved it out  did some stupid mistake in fragment code.

Comment: Official doc for reference - https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images